# Can't authenticate Twitter using SimpleAuth

Tags: ios, twitter, react-native, twitter-oauth

Am using **react-native-simple-auth** in my **React-native** Project. 
**Google-web** is working fine but am facing issue in twitter.
am getting the following error

There is no class registered to handle twitter requests.' was thrown while invoking authorize on target SimpleAuthWrapper with params (
    twitter,
    37
)

[image]

am also facing build issue throwing this error

[image]

if i uncheck the target membership of SimpleAuth build is successful but twitter oauth is not working.

this is my pod file

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
target 'NewsguruRN' do
pod 'SimpleAuth/GoogleWeb'
pod 'SimpleAuth/Twitter'
xcodeproj './ios/Newsguru.xcodeproj'
end
```

please any one help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TO resolve the above issue we need to set the header search path to $(PODROOT),
then it will be resolved